# Strange padding issue using NAV UL

Tags: html, css

My webpage has a list and I want the list to start just a few pixels down. The problem is, when I set `margin: 0 0 0 0;` it naturally does nothing, but setting `margin:  1px 0 0 0 ;` causes it to 'jump' down many pixels.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hebdjx7h/)**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Layer This</li>
        <li>And that</li>
        <li>Ooooh</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    background:#f0364f;
}

nav ul  {
    padding:1px 0 0 0; /* THIS IS THE FAULT.  */
}

nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:20px 0;
    background:#B8C5CD;
    padding:5px;
}
```

So, in the CSS, if you change from

```
nav ul  {
    padding:1px 0 0 0; /* THIS IS THE FAULT.  */
}
```

to

```
nav ul  {
    padding:0 0 0 0; /* THIS IS RENDERING CORRECTLY BUT, I WANT A PADDING!  */
}
```

You will see the issue. When the padding is set to 0 it works as expected. Why does adding 1 pixel make it jump so far down?

**EDIT**  Please note, although a fix is nice, I'm more interested in why this behaviour occurs (I'm sure I can find a hack easily enough, but I could not find any information into understanding the cause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you have no padding on your `<ul>` the margin for your top list item collapses. When it has padding, the margin is acknowledged.

I'm assuming from your question that you don't want any margin before the first list item, you can remove any margin from the first item easily:

```
nav ul li:first-child{
    margin-top:0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hebdjx7h/9/)

See [Margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Brilliant - now I know what element I'm trying to affect (the `UL`) has let me easily change the padding/margins etc to understand it. Thank yo.

Comment: Glad to have helped. (:

Comment: @George I knew how to solve it but your answer showcased why its happening, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You set `margin` for your `li` (child element). When you set `padding` for `ul` (parent element), you passed [**margin collapsing**](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/).

Set `margin` for second `li` element and next:

```
nav ul li + li {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hebdjx7h/10/).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `:first-child`, I would prefer doing something as mentioned below because `:first-child` may have cross browser compatibility issues.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">Layer This</li>
    <li>And that</li>
    <li>Ooooh</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

nav ul li.first{
 margin-top:0;
}
```

The solution is basically same but targeting element based on class rather than `:first-child` may just help you prevent some cross browser issues.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving padding to first child instead of ul

```
nav ul li.test {
    padding-top:1px;
}

nav ul  {
    padding:0 0 0 0;
}

<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="test">Layer This</li>
    <li>And that</li>
    <li>Ooooh</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```